# Generate a datediff from a single column in the table, sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Shift    Time                    Action
TA      2021-03-17 10:39:11.613    OF
TA      2021-03-17 11:09:11.353    ON
TA      2021-03-17 13:49:20.760    OF
TA      2021-03-17 14:10:20.760    ON
```

Hi, I wanted to know if you can help me. I have a table of inputs and outputs. I record the time and date it happens.
But for reporting purposes I need to make a datediff with that column. Anyone have any idea how I could generate my query to achieve the following resul.

```
Shift    Time                    Action       Shift    Time                    Action
TA      2021-03-17 10:39:11.613    OF          TA       2021-03-17 11:09:11.353    ON
TA      2021-03-17 13:49:20.760    OF          TA       2021-03-17 14:10:20.760    ON
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the values interleave exactly, you can use `lead()` and then filter:

```
select *
from (select shift, time, action,
             lead(time) over (partition by shift order by time) as next_time,
             lead(action) over (partition by shift order by time) as next_action
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'OF';
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just and precise what I needed

Comment: @juliohernandez . . . Note:  This assumes that the records are perfectly interleaved.  If they are not, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.